# Animal Harmony in Aldur's Vale

Tags: david-eddings

In Malloreon, Belgarath states that "Aldur's presence allows animals to live in harmony".

However, in Polgara The Sorceress, a hawk almost eats her while she's playing a a squirrel in "The Tree", which is decidedly not "harmonious".

Are there other points which would resolve this discrepancy? Could the agressivity of monsters after Torak broke the world in two be related to that harmony (reflecting the loss of harmony between Gods?)

Comment: Polgara was not, technically, an animal. I don't have the scene on hand, but it's entirely possible that technicality gave the hawk the opportunity to eat squirrel, a rare delicacy in the Vale. :P

Comment: Wasn't that hawk a visitor, and not a resident of the vale?

Comment: @CBredlow The hawk comes up later, which suggests he's at least a regular visitor.

Comment: @Kheldar Belgarath did hunt down field mice when he and Polgara lived together a few times

Comment: It's hard to see how a hawk (an obligate carnivore) could live in harmony with other small mammals and birds since if it doesn't eat them, it dies.

Comment: @Valorum I suppose either it eats outside the Vale, or divine sustenance provides an alternate option. I am not Aldur to argue the point decisively. I do, however, still wonder about the significance from a literary pov.